# How to use cordova-filechooser to open file on Android

Tags: angular, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm develoing an Android app with Angular and Cordova, and I need to open a file with an user interaction, so I installed this Cordova plugin https://github.com/don/cordova-filechooser

```sh
cordova plugin add https://github.com/don/cordova-filechooser.git --save
yarn install
```

In order to use plugin i write this code

```js
declare var fileChooser: any;
...
fileChooser.open(function(uri) {
    alert('File is: ' + uri);
});
```

but the console says 'fileChooser is not defined'.

What is the correct way to use this plugin?

Cordova: 9.0.0 - Node: 10.15.0 - Angular: 7.0.4

Thank you

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a more updated fork of this plugin available at https://github.com/ihadeed/cordova-filechooser
2. You could probably use Ionic Native for Angular, which gives a more Angular like API: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-chooser
3. Otherwise you should be able to work with `fileChooser` directly, as this is the JS object that is added to the global scope (make sure to wait for the deviceready event before trying to access it)

Comment: Then my use is correct ? 

declare var fileChooser: any;
...
fileChooser.open(function(uri) {
    alert('File is: ' + uri);
});

Comment: That I can't tell you - although it doesn't look wrong, yes (my Angular/TS is very rusty) But if you execute `fileChooser` manually in the console via remote debugging of your Cordova app, you should get a result to verify that the object is actually there.