# Upload files in cordova

Tags: angular, cordova

I have to upload zip and xlsx files from device to server. So I googled and found https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cordova/cordova_file_system.htm . But this doesn't work. It always throw window.requestFileSystem is not a function. So is there any plugins to read the device file system in cordova. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some recommendation for you, i used these plugins before:

To open the file chooser in phone so that user can browse and select the file:
`cordova-plugin-filechooser` :https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-filechooser

To get the filepath after user selecting the file: `cordova-plugin-filepath` :https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-filepath

To read the file and convert to Blob so that can upload to server: `cordova-plugin-file` https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/

Here is an example how to integrate 3 library in JS to make user select a pdf file in their phone and upload to server, you can based on it to convert to angular

```
uploadFile() {
  let vm = this;
  let filter = { "mime": "application/pdf" };
  // open file chooser
  fileChooser.open(filter, function(uri) {
    // change content:// to path:///
    window.FilePath.resolveNativePath(uri, function(fs) {
      vm.successCallback(fs)
    }, vm.onError());
  });
},


  successCallback(localFileUri) {
      let vm = this;
      // open file using path
      let fileFormat = localFileUri.substr(localFileUri.length - 4);
      // manually rejected if not pdf, because mime filter is not working on some phone
      if (fileFormat !== ".pdf") {

        return false;
      }
      window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(localFileUri, function(fs) {
        console.log(fs);
        fs.file(function(res) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onloadend = (evt) => {
            var fileBlob = new Blob([evt.target.result], { type: "application/pdf" });
            vm.sendToServer({ file: fileBlob, name: fs.name });
          };
          reader.readAsArrayBuffer(res);
        })
      }, vm.onError());
    },
```

Comment: Hi I have defined fileChooser as 'declare var fileChooser;' but it says fileChooser is not defined

Comment: does it said in the IDE or when you serve in your pc/laptop chrome ? if that is the case then ignore it, it will works fine when you build the apk (for android) and install in the real phone

Comment: I testing with the real phone MOTO G android version 6.0.1

Comment: im not sure about angular and maybe some dependecies in your project conflicts, you may try the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56260415/how-to-use-cordova-filechooser-to-open-file-on-android